# window.location.search

Tags: javascript

Can window.location.search be null or undefined in any browser? Most of them i tried IE8/9, FF, Chrome, Safari is all empty strings.

Just want to know if i have to null check before doing string operation on it.

Answer (score 3):

Should be empty strings. But using type conversion:

```
if(window.location.search)
```

will work in any case. If the search is set, it will definitely be a non empty string and evaluate to true then.

Or use `typeof`:

```
if(typeof window.location.search === "string")
```

but this is also true for an empty string. It depends on what you want to do in the end.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, location.search can be an empty string even though a ?key=value part is present in the URL.